# Wrap Menu text thru MenuStyle

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have this custom MenuStyle that makes a Menu look like a dropdown:

```
struct DropdownMenuStyle: MenuStyle {
    func makeBody(configuration: Configuration) -> some View {
        HStack {
            Menu(configuration)
            Spacer()
            Text("⌵").offset(y: -4)
        }
        .padding(4)
        .overlay(
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 5).stroke(.gray, lineWidth: 1)
        )
        .foregroundColor(.black)
    }
}
```

Which looks like this:

[image]

The problem is only the text "Label" is tapable to view the menu. The surrounding box does not respond. This is because the way I currently have it setup the box wraps Menu, not the Label inside.

What I would like to do is something like this:

```
struct DropdownMenuStyle: MenuStyle {
    func makeBody(configuration: Configuration) -> some View {
        Menu(content: configuration.content, label: {
            HStack {
                Text(configuration.label)
                Spacer()
                Text("⌵").offset(y: -4)
            }
            .padding(4)
            .overlay(
                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 5).stroke(.gray, lineWidth: 1)
            )
            .foregroundColor(.black)
        })
    }
}
```

But MenuConfiguration doesn't seem to export anything useful.

It seems like the only way to do this is by wrapping the Menu view like this:

```
struct DropdownMenu<Content: View>: View {
    let label: String
    @ViewBuilder var content: () -> Content
        
    var body: some View {
        Menu(content: {
            content()
        }, label: {
            HStack {
                Text(label)
                Spacer()
                Text("⌵").offset(y: -4)
            }
            .padding(4)
            .overlay(
                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 5).stroke(.gray, lineWidth: 1)
            )
            .foregroundColor(.black)
        })
    }
}
```

I know with TextFieldStyle, makeBody isn't exported and the recommended way of implementing that is something like this (where I think _body is private):

```
struct CustomTextFieldStyle: TextFieldStyle {
    func _body(configuration: TextField<_Label>) -> some View {
        configuration
            .padding(4)
            .overlay(
                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 5).stroke(.gray, lineWidth: 1)
            )
    }
}
```

Is there a way to do this with a MenuStyle that I've overlooked? The goal is to be able to pass a style thru environment. With the View wrapper I have to replace every instance.

Comment: Try adding `.contentShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 5))` after the `.overlay()`.

Answer (score 0):

The clickable area should be a part of label, so here is a possible approach - wrap everything into custom dropdown button.

Tested with Xcode 13.2 / iOS 15.2

[image: demo]

```
struct DemoView: View {
    var body: some View {
        DropdownMenuButton {
            Button("Test1") {}
            Button("Test2") {}
        } label: {
            Text("Label")
        }
        .frame(width: 200)
    }

    struct DropdownMenuButton<Label, Content> : View where Label : View, Content : View {
        @ViewBuilder let content: () -> Content
        @ViewBuilder let label: () -> Label

        var body: some View {
            Menu(content: self.content,
            label: {
                HStack {
                    self.label()
                    Spacer()
                    Text("⌵").offset(y: -4)
                }
            })
            .menuStyle(DropdownMenuStyle())
        }
    }

    struct DropdownMenuStyle: MenuStyle {
        func makeBody(configuration: Configuration) -> some View {
            Menu(configuration)
                .padding(4)
                .overlay(
                    RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 5).stroke(.gray, lineWidth: 1)
                )
                .contentShape(Rectangle())
                .foregroundColor(.black)
        }
    }

}
```